# What is wrong with my cross compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a basic program that i can get to cross compile on my mac. I am running Mac OS X Mavericks. My cross compiler is arm-elf-gcc-4.7.3. I wrote a simple test program that looks like:

```
int main()
{
    ;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run /opt/local/bin/arm-elf-gcc-4.7.3 -o test test.c I receive these errors.

```
test.c:4:Unknown pseudo-op: .global
test.c:4:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 109 (m).
test.c:5:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
test.c:5:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 109 (m).
test.c:7:Junk character 64 (@).
test.c:7:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 32 ( ).
test.c:8:Junk character 64 (@).
test.c:8:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 32 ( ).
test.c:9:Junk character 64 (@).
test.c:9:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 32 ( ).
test.c:10:invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[sp'
test.c:11:too many memory references for `add'
test.c:12:expecting operand after ','; got nothing
test.c:13:too many memory references for `mov'
test.c:14:too many memory references for `add'
test.c:15:no such instruction: `ldmfd sp!, {fp}'
test.c:16:no such instruction: `bx lr'
test.c:17:Unknown pseudo-op: .size
```

What is wrong with my cross compiler?

Comment: What do you expect to achieve with ; ?

Comment: It looks like the C compiler is being given assembler as C source and doesn't like it much.  What was the command line you used to compile the code?

Comment: I am trying to do a sanity check by making sure this most basic program compiles before I try and compile my heavier code.

Comment: and I used /opt/local/bin/arm-elf-gcc-4.7.3 -o test test.c to compile

Comment: Try passing gcc the '-v' option, it shows exactly what it runs when it tries to compile your code.

Comment: it looks like it is trying to use the wrong assembler. Is there a way to specify to use the arm-elf-at assembler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler was using the wrong assembler. I had to specify the prefix with -B/opt/local/arm-elf-

Comment: While you technically answered the question, it would be better to have an answer that explains _why_ the cross-compiler might be using the wrong assembler and what to do about for the benefit of anyone trying to build a cross compiler.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Reads like the compiler spat out assembly the assembler couldn't read. Check for mismatches.

Comment: I think it might be because the cross compiler is using the wrong assembler. Is there a way to specify a different assembler to use?