# gcc cross compiler is using the wrong assembler

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

When I run:

```
/opt/local/bin/arm-elf-gcc-4.7 test.c -o test
```

`gcc` decides to use `as -o test.o test.s` instead of the cross compiler's assembler. How do I specify the correct assembler to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with my cross compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714228/what-is-wrong-with-my-cross-compiler)

Comment: Investigate the `-B` option to `gcc`.  Have you ever been able to cross-compile with this compiler?  If so, investigate what changed.  If not, check that you did the installation correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -B PREFIX to set the correct assembler.

Comment: There are other gcc cross compilers out there that do not require this option at run time (like AVRDUDE) so there must be a better way.