# Using gcc 2.8.1 on 68HC16; make install problem

Tags: c, gcc

long story short, I want to compile some legacy code using GCC for the 68HC16 (originally based on a commercial compiler).

I found a patch here:

http://www.realtime.bc.ca/open-source/gnu-hc1x.html

It's a patch on gcc 2.8.1 and binutils 2.9.1. I was able to compile it with some adjustment on Cygwin/gcc.

It's compiling correctly in the directory gcc is compiled but when I do the 'make install' and try to run it from /home/me, the HC16 assembler is not selected and compilation failed.

Any idea where to look on how to fix this ?

```
$ hc16-coff-gcc -c test.c

/tmp/ccyqP57A.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccyqP57A.s:2: Error: no such instruction: `section .text'
/tmp/ccyqP57A.s:3: Error: no such instruction: `align 1'
/tmp/ccyqP57A.s:5: Error: no such instruction: `global _f'
/tmp/ccyqP57A.s:6: Error: no such instruction: `_f'
/tmp/ccyqP57A.s:7: Error: no such instruction: `pshm z'
...
```

Comment: can you use a newer GCC version? Even 4.x is so ancient nowadays

Comment: The HC1x patch is the only available for this GCC version and I had to work hard to make it compile with GCC 7.4.0.

Comment: Got something here as dirty fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714228/what-is-wrong-with-my-cross-compiler